# How to write 0x00 into file

Tags: c, cocoa, posix, stringstream

I'm writing some application which will communicate (write only) with my custom USB-serial device. It is Cocoa (OS X) application and part which is related to this writing is coded in POSIX style.

I have solved mostly all things but have issues with NULL (0x00) character.

For example lets says that I need to white 5 characters to a file.

My code is as follow:

```
char stringAsChar[5];

stringAsChar[0] = 0x77;
stringAsChar[1] = 0x44;
stringAsChar[2] = 0x00; //here is an problem
stringAsChar[3] = 0x05;
stringAsChar[4] = 0xFF;
...
fputs(stringAsChar, file); // write to file
```

Each character at specified index represents data for some registers into target device.

The problem arise when stream include 0x00 character which i need to have as data, writing is stopped there (0x00 interpreted as stop of stream).

How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fputs` works with `NUL`-terminated strings. If you want to write `NUL` characters to a file you can use `fwrite` instead:

```
noOfBytesWritten = fwrite(stringAsChar, 1, noOfBytesToWrite, file);
```

Comment: Great, thank you and all other users for similar answers. It works like this with ordinary files, I need to test with real device writing to /dev/cu.myusbdevice.

Comment: Yes, it works with writing to /dev/cu.myusbdevice. Problem solved ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try using `fwrite` instead. It lets you specify the amount of bytes written to the stream. Or loop over your characters and use `fputc`.

Comment: fputc is only useful if a) you like your code to run slowly or b) you need to take its address. Otherwise use putc (ditto for fgetc and getc ... fortunately there's no fgetchar for people to screw up with in these latter days when the reason for the existence of fgetc and fputc has been forgotten).

Comment: @JimBalter Sure, but OP had an array of 5 chars.

Comment: @JimBalter C doesn't specify any requirements in regards to speed, in this scenario. In fact, it gives plenty of room for optimisation: "The least requirements on a conforming implementation are: ... At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that
execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced. ..."

Answer (score 3):

`fputs()` works with null-terminated strings. You cannot have a NULL embedded in a C string because it's the terminator.  You can use `fputc()` to write a NULL byte to a file.